# Looking for ideas to make wire connectors compatible with Lego Functions

Tags: power-functions

I like to make custom battery packs for Lego Power Functions. Is there any simple way to make wire connectors?

The only option that comes to my mind is to buy LEGO Power Functions Extension Wire # 8886, cut the wire, and connect it to my custom battery pack. Would that work? Is there a better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only option comes to my mind is to buy LEGO Power Functions Extension Wire # 8886, cut the wire, and connect it to my custom battery pack. Would that work?

Yes it would work, and people have done it.

Here's [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr8ZOnIzlVE) someone has made on their own custom Power Functions batteries.

[image: YouTube video]

> Is there a better idea?

I don't think it would really be possible to produce a Power Functions compatible connector for less that the $3 LEGO charges for their cable at a small scale, so that's probably your cheapest option.

Comment: The video is helpful. When I searched youtube, I could not find anything. May I ask how did you find the video?

Comment: @AllanXu I had searched `custom lego power function battery` on YouTube, and it was one of the results.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have done so. Wanted to motorize the Wall-E set. Initially did so with a AAA lego battery box in his belly, but with the wires and everything, not really enough room.

So I indeed cut up an 8886 extension wire and connected the wires to a clip you can get in any electronics store on which fits a 9V block battery.

When powering an SBrick or IR-receiver, only the outer wires need to be connected to the clip. When connecting immediately to motor or PF switch, only the inner wires need to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

I made a battery holder following these instructions:

[www.instructables.com/id/Lego-AA-Battery-Holder](http://www.instructables.com/id/Lego-AA-Battery-Holder/)

[image: Battery holder image]

It works great even without glue. It requires only Lego and 4 clips.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks! That looks like a nice way to make a custom battery box. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to answer the question about how to make connectors for a custom battery box. We're really looking for answers that directly answer questions rather than those that might add to a conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This triggers so many other good ideas as well. The idea can be done with simpler bricks as well. Perforated bricks are harder to find.

Comment: This is just an alternative way =) Do not use (and try to somehow connect) the original holder, but make everything from simple parts...